# MkDocs get full sitemap

Tags: xml, static-site, mkdocs

I am the owner of Nasix.js.org and I want to know how to get the sitemap. It should auto generated but it seems not to work. See nasix.js.org/sitemap.xml. All the docs say it will just be there but it isn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You need to set the [site_url](https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/configuration/#site_url) configuration setting in your `mkdocs.yml` configuration file:

```
site_url: https://nasix.js.org/
```

Traditionaly, links in sitemaps should contain the fully qualified URL to a page. Therefore, the sitemap is build using the `canonical_url` for each page. However, without a `site_url`, MkDocs does not know what domain to use and the `canonical_url` is not set. As a result, the sitemap will consist of blank entries.

Note that in [mkdocs/mkdocs#1783](https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/issues/1783) there is a discussion about raising a warning of some kind when the `site_url` is not set.

Comment: It works. According to https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/configuration/#site_url the default value of site_url variable is null